# como unir dos arreglos de elementos enteros en un nuevo arreglo

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Examen1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       int arr1[]={201,90,56,5,1};
       int arr2[]={909111,15000,8342,1001,900,20};
       Examen1 resultado = new Examen1();
       int resul[] =resultado.sumaArr(arr1, arr2);
       System.out.println("Este es el arreglo 1: "+Arrays.toString(arr1));
       System.out.println("Este es el arreglo 1 ordenado de menor a mayor: 
 "+Arrays.toString(ordena1(arr1)));
       System.out.println("");
       System.out.println("Este es el arreglo 2: "+Arrays.toString(arr2));
       System.out.println("Este es el arreglo 2 ordenado de menor a mayor: "+Arrays.toString(ordena2(arr2)));
       System.out.println("");
       System.out.println("Esta es la union de los arreglos 1 y2: "+Arrays.toString(sumaArr(arr1,arr2)));
       System.out.println("Este es el arreglo ordenado de menor a mayor: "+Arrays.toString(ordena(resul)));
    }
    public static int[] sumaArr(int arr1[],int arr2[]){
        int arr3[] = new int[arr1.length + arr2.length];
        for(int i=0; i < arr2.length;i++){
            arr3[i]=arr2[i];
        }
        int p=0;
        for(int i= arr2.length;i <arr1.length + arr2.length;i++){
            arr3[i]=arr1[p++];
        }
        return arr3;
    }
    public static int[] ordena(int resul[]){
        int aux;
        int ordenado[]= new int[resul.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < resul.length;i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < resul.length-1;j++){
                if(resul[j] > resul[j+1]){
                    aux = resul[j];
                    resul[j]=resul[j+1];
                    resul[j+1]= aux;
                }
                ordenado[j]=resul[j];
            }
        }
        return ordenado;

    }  
    public static int[] ordena1(int arr1[]){
        int aux;
        for(int i = 0; i < arr1.length;i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < arr1.length-1;j++){
                if(arr1[j] > arr1[j+1]){
                    aux = arr1[j];
                    arr1[j]=arr1[j+1];
                    arr1[j+1]= aux;
                }
            }
        }
        return arr1;
    }  
     public static int[] ordena2(int arr2[]){
        int aux;
        for(int i = 0; i < arr2.length;i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < arr2.length-1;j++){
                if(arr2[j] > arr2[j+1]){
                    aux = arr2[j];
                    arr2[j]=arr2[j+1];
                    arr2[j+1]= aux;
                }
               
            }
        }
        return arr2;
    }  
}
```

al ejecutar me sale esto

Este es el arreglo 1: [201, 90, 56, 5, 1]
Este es el arreglo 1 ordenado de menor a mayor: [1, 5, 56, 90, 201]

Este es el arreglo 2: [909111, 15000, 8342, 1001, 900, 20]
Este es el arreglo 2 ordenado de menor a mayor: [20, 900, 1001, 8342, 15000, 909111]

Esta es la unión de los arreglos 1 y2: [20, 900, 1001, 8342, 15000, 909111, 1, 5, 56, 90, 201]
Este es el arreglo ordenado de menor a mayor: [1, 5, 20, 56, 90, 201, 900, 1001, 8342, 15000, 0]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

cuando se ordena la unión de los arreglos aparece 0 y no se por que no sale el ultimo numero que es 909111

Comment: Eres consciente de que tienes 3 funciones exactamente iguales? Puedes deshacerte de 2 y quedarte con una sola.

Comment: Como hago eso bro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Parte tu pregunta en problemas concretos y detalla el
   contexto. No estás indicando qué tipo de método de ordenación
   esperas en ordena()
2. En stackoverflow no se admiten preguntas "urgentes". Si tienes prisa lo mejor que puedes hacer es ofrecer recompensas, cuando tengas más reputación.

### Respondiendo a la pregunta que no has planteado.

La razón por la que te sale 0 en el último array es porque no estás escribiendo nada en la última posición. Si quieres una copia del original en ordenado copia tras el bucle.

```
    public static int[] ordena(int resul[]) {
        int aux;
        int ordenado[] = new int[resul.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < resul.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < resul.length - 1; j++) {
                if (resul[j] > resul[j + 1]) {
                    aux = resul[j];
                    resul[j] = resul[j + 1];
                    resul[j + 1] = aux;
                }
            }
        }
        
        ordenado = Arrays.copyOf(resul, resul.length);
        return ordenado;
    }
```

Esto soluciona el problema que tienes pero realmente todo este código es redundante teniendo ya las otras funciones (**que por cierto, ¿son iguales?**), y no estás haciendo nada nuevo. Además estás alterando el original igualmente. Si no especificas qué quieres hacer con este otro método no podemos ayudarte.

Por cierto, considera indicar el tipo array junto al tipo, es decir: `int[] ordenados` en lugar de `int ordenados[]`. Esta sintaxis que usas se admitió por simplificar la adaptación a Java a programadores de C, pero hace ya años que quedó obsoleta.

Comment: Hola buenas tardes ya lo resolví antes de ver tu respuesta y se agradece la respuesta, lo que hice fue eliminar el  Int ordenado[]= new int[resul.length]; , y en ves del return ordenado puse return resul;

Comment: Me alegra que hayas resuelto tu problema. Considera marcar esta respuesta como aceptada. Observando tu respuesta, haciendo eso estás literalmente copiando las otras 2 funciones, teniendo literalmente 3 funciones iguales.

Comment: y otra cosa si no es mucha molestia se que tengo tres métodos iguales lo que no se es como usar solo un método para todo lo demás, me podrías ayudar con eso por favor? apenas estoy aprendiendo java

Comment: @DarkAngeLink Simplemente bórralos y usa solo uno.

Comment: pero como ago eso es lo que no se

Comment: En lugar de usar ordena1() y ordena2() usa ordena() para todos. Es decir, sí sabes llamar a métodos, porque lo estás haciendo. No entiendo exactamente cuál es el problema.

Comment: Ese es el problema que no se apenas soy principiante en esto

Comment: Donde ponga ordena1 y ordena2 pon simplemente ordena

Comment: eso lo se pero como utilizo ese ordena para ordenar los arr1 y arr2?

Comment: Pues dado que tu ordena está ordenando "in place", con ¿ordena(arr1) y ordena(arr2) no te funciona?

Si no, arr1 = ordena(arr1)

Comment: Ya lo vi muchas gracias bro

Comment: @DarkAngeLink hazte un favor y mira algunos tutoriales y práctica cosas simples. Luego puedes combinarlas y hacer cosas más complejas pero aunque seas principiante, necesitas practicar de a poco con lo que ya sabes para afianzar los conocimientos. Por ejemplo, lo de las 3 funciones. Son exactamente iguales, lo único que cambia es el nombre. Es como tener 3 cortadoras de césped. ¿Para que quieres 3 si con una te basta y te sobra?  Te prometo que puedes pensar muchas analogías con la vida real y te ayudarán a digerir cualquier concepto nuevo, aunque no sea de programación.

Comment: @Mateo lo primero que hice fue buscar en YouTube pero no encontré nada bro y mi ultima opción fue aquí,